# Action Bar icon that live by its own rules (and doesn't know bounds)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I would like to know if something like this is possible, and it would be good if somebody gave me a hint how to achieve it. [image]

I can think of only one way how to do it, put

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and add view above activity that looks like an action bar with a icon that goes beyond this pseidoaction bar. But are there some better way how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is the way how to do it. 
 1. Forget about standard action bar;
 2. Make your own action bar view.
 3. Use android:clipChildren="false".
 4. code (some additional code - pasted from my project):

ActionBar representing class view:

```
public class DefaultHeading extends RelativeLayout {

    private View mCartIcon;
    private TextView mCount;
    private ImageView mDefaultImage;
    private TextView mHeadingTitle;
    private SearchView mSearch;
    private int mLogo;
    private View mLeftView;
    private View mReset;
    private ViewFlipper mSwitcher;
    private ImageView mGrid;
    private View mShare;
    private String mTitle;
    private boolean mBackButtonEnabled;
    private boolean mPlainHeading;
    private ImageView mLeftButton;

    public DefaultHeading(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.defaultheading, 0, 0);
        try {
            mTitle = array.getString(R.styleable.defaultheading_headingtitle);
            mBackButtonEnabled = array.getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.defaultheading_backbutton, false);
            mPlainHeading = array.getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.defaultheading_plainLogo, false);
        } finally {
            array.recycle();
        }
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.default_heading, this, true);
        mCartIcon = findViewById(R.id.buy);
        mCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemsInCart);
        mDefaultImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.default_header_dvor_logo);
        mHeadingTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headingTitle);
        mSearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        mLeftView = findViewById(R.id.leftView);
        mReset = findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mSwitcher = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mShare = findViewById(R.id.share);
        mGrid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        mLeftButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        setViewInfo();
        setListeners();
    }

    private void setViewInfo() {
        if (mTitle != null) {
            mHeadingTitle.setText(mTitle);
        }
        if (mPlainHeading) {
            showMiniDvor();
            hideControlLayout();
        }
        if (mBackButtonEnabled) {
            mLeftButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.back_btn);
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener searchListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearch.setSelected(!mSearch.isSelected());
            giveSearchMaxPlace(mSearch.isSelected());

        }
    };
    private OnCloseListener closeListener = new OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            mSearch.setSelected(!mSearch.isSelected());
            giveSearchMaxPlace(mSearch.isSelected());
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void giveSearchMaxPlace(boolean morePlace) {
        if (morePlace) {
            mHeadingTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mHeadingTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void hide() {
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void show() {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void setQueryListener(OnQueryTextListener listener) {
        mSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(listener);
    }

    public void changeGridImage(int image) {
        mGrid.setImageResource(image);
    }

    public void setOnGridListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mGrid.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void showCartProgress() {

    }

    public void hideCartProgress() {

    }

    private void setListeners() {
        mSearch.setOnSearchClickListener(searchListener);
        mSearch.setOnCloseListener(closeListener);
    }

    public void setResetListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mReset.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void showResetLayout() {
        giveSearchMaxPlace(false);
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);
    }

    public void showGridLayout() {
        giveSearchMaxPlace(false);
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(2);
    }

    public void showShareLayout() {
        mShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        giveSearchMaxPlace(false);
        hideSearch();
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    }

    public void showMainLayout() {
        mShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        showSearch();
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    }

    public void showOnlyCart() {
        mShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hideSearch();
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    }

    public void hideControlLayout() {
        giveSearchMaxPlace(false);
        mSwitcher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showReset() {
        mReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideReset() {
        mReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void hideSearch() {
        mSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showSearch() {
        mSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void setSearchHintText(String hint) {
        mSearch.setQueryHint(hint);
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        mSearch.setQuery(query, false);
    }

    public void setMenuListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mLeftView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void setCartListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mCartIcon.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void setShareListner(OnClickListener listener) {
        mShare.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    public void showFullDvor() {
        mLogo = R.drawable.default_header_dvor_logo;
        mDefaultImage.setImageResource(mLogo);
    }

    public void showMiniDvor() {
        mLogo = R.drawable.plain_header_dvor_logo;
        mDefaultImage.setImageResource(mLogo);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mHeadingTitle.setText(title);
    }

    public void setProductCountInCart(int count) {
        mCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        if (count > 0) {
            mCount.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_without_border);
            mCartIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_without_border);
        } else {
            mCount.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_gray);
            mCartIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_gray);
        }
        if (count > 99) {

            mCount.setTextSize(8);
        } else if (count > 9) {
            mCount.setTextSize(10);
        } else {
            mCount.setTextSize(16);
        }
    }

}
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_header_menu_btn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/default_header_dvor_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/default_header_dvor_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:lines="2"            
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buy"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buy" >
            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buy"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buy"
                android:src="@drawable/connect_with_us"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buy"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/default_header_cart_btn" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemsInCart"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="RESET"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftView" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/grid" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Use case in activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ...//more code}
```

Activities layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.dvor.androidapp"
    android:id="@+id/slaidingLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false" > //All Parents of DefaultHeading need this.

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false" > //All Parents of DefaultHeading need this.

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp" //Default headings height - 1dp, don't use layout_below it can cause sliced icon.
            android:background="#1d1d1d" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"                
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="50dp" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <com.mobileapp.commons.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/titles"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#272727"
                android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                app:selectedBold="true"
                app1:footerColor="#8b0005"
                app1:footerLineHeight="0dp"
                app1:titlePadding="50dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <YOURPACKAGE.DefaultHeading // put it after main content layout, or there can be flickerring. 
            android:id="@+id/dvorHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false" >
        </YOURPACKAGE.DefaultHeading>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progess"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#1d1d1d"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```